# La página ha rechazado la conexión. He visto esta pregunta pero no he entendido las respuestas

Tags: html

Soy nueva en HTML y tengo un problema con los links, que acabo de aprender a ponerlos.
Cada vez que trato de clickear en el link, sale "La página x ha rechazado la conexión" He probado con links de vídeos y webs y buscado cómo solucionarlo pero no funciona.

He visto la misma pregunta en esta página pero no he entendido la respuesta. Aquí está el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href= "https://www.google.es/" "_blank"> Google </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como todos los lenguajes de marcado, HTML tiene su sintaxis. Una etiqueta puede tener atributos sin valor (porque no lo requiere) pero no valores sin un atributo al que se aplique. Tu rompes la sintaxis con `"_blank"`.

Answer (score 0):

prueba lo siguiente:

```
<a href= "https://www.google.es/" target="_blank"> Google </a>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero eso, a pesar que corrije su error de sintaxis, no da la respuesta que espera pues dice: **He visto la misma pregunta en esta página pero no he entendido la respuesta.** , por lo que espera una aclaración además de la respuesta, y en tu respuesta es solo código sin más. Además podrias recibir votos negativos [por contestar con solo código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/263200).  Edita la respuesta con una breve explicación de tu solución para que esté bien documentada y el OP obtenga la respuesta esperada, gracias.